# On Clear color face trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am create label and button programatically . My concerned is on longPress gesture it color change .its work fine. And when user tap on another previous button and label color became clear. My button work fine but my previous label not clear Color.

```
- (void)handleLongPress :(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Long press Ended");
        appDelegate.selectedTag =gestureRecognizer.view.tag;



    } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {



        UILabel *previousLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:appDelegate.selectedTag];
        NSLog(@"%@",previousLabel);

        previousLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];



        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

        button.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:0.102 green:0.776 blue:0.557 alpha:1];

       UILabel *label=(UILabel *)gestureRecognizer.view;
          label.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.102 green:0.776 blue:0.557 alpha:1];



        UIButton *previousbutton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:appDelegate.selectedTag];

        previousbutton.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button and label have same tag in "self.view".

In your situation tag must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are facing this problem due to same tag of UIButton and UILabel.

Please follow [iOS: Find all controls with the same tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508033/ios-find-all-controls-with-the-same-tag) this link. May be your problem get resolved.

All the best !